# What are the differences between "inform" and "notice"?

Tags: word-usage, sentence-choice

I am trying to make a sentence in a IT document. 
At the first line, I'd like to say that "This document inform you that ~~".
The verb "inform" is correct for it? Or is there any proper template for this kind of situation?

Comment: I think your question *title* should have been asking about ***notify***, not ***notice***. In which context *This document **notifies** you that...* is just a slightly more "starchy" alternative to ***informs***.

Comment: Can you clarify the context.  Are you giving information about a specific event, such as a planned server outage over the weekend, or more detailed information, like all the steps to install and configure a particle software package?